# Why does the integral for a "generic one-loop snail diagram" in scalar QFT blow up?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, integration, dimensional-analysis, singularities

I am embarrassed to ask this but I can't figure it out. Say we are in scalar QFT and we have a Feynman diagram like the following (straight from my course notes)
[image]

Apparently this integral blows up for $large$ $q$ and that's why we need to do something like introduce a momentum cutoff. My misunderstanding here is that I see this integral blowing up for $small$ q and so clearly I don't understand this integral at all. Can somebody please be kind and help me out? I know this is probably a dumb  question but I really need to understand this and I'm not getting very far on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It blows up for large $q$ because of the integral measure, $\operatorname{d}^4q$. One way of writing that after Wick rotation is $$\Omega_4 q^3 \operatorname{d}q,$$ which grows as $q$ for $q\gg m$. Note that $\Omega_4$ is the [solid angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle#Solid_angles_in_arbitrary_dimensions) in $4$-dimensional space.

That comes from the fact that in [hyperspherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates) the volume element is given by
$$\operatorname{d}^4q = q^3 \sin^2(\phi_1)\,\sin(\phi_2) \operatorname{d}q \operatorname{d}\phi_1 \operatorname{d}\phi_2 \operatorname{d}\phi_3.$$
Doing the angular integrals yields $\Omega_4$ because the integrand is invariant under $4$-d rotations.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm struggling with generic misunderstanding of how to do relativistic integrals. Is there a resource you can point me to? I understand multidimensional calc but there's some kind of missing piece here for me. I don't understand why your answer is correct, even though I know it is (it's basically the next line in my notes).

Comment: I don't have a handy link to a reference. Do you understand Wick rotations? I ask because Wick rotations turn relativistic integrals into Euclidean ones, so once you've Wick rotated, it becomes a straightforward application of Jacobians, and the definition of solid angle.

Comment: Yes, not perfectly, but I get the general idea and they make sense. I suppose if I just think about it after a Wick rotation it all makes sense, but I struggle with a physical intuition. Thanks so much - I think your answer is what I needed since I hadn't refreshed my memory on Wick rotations until now.

Comment: A small followup: are Wick rotations the main way to deal with relativistic integrals?

Comment: @SChoice In QFT, I believe that's the case. I am not actually an expert on Wick rotations, just how to handle things once the rotation is done.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much for all your help! I really appreciate it.